# What is the inherent mechanism in carbocatalysis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis, aromaticity, carbon-allotropes, organocatalysis

When checking non-metallic catalysis materials, one mentioned example is that of carbocatalysis; using heterogeneous carbon structure to catalyze a reaction (Not to be confused as a support surface for other metallic catalysts, like palladium).

I imagine that the aromatic conjugation of pi electron's has a part to play; yet the mechanism is clearly different from established metal catalysts.

Comment: @Maurice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbocatalysis

Comment: I am aware of the wikipedia link. Yet, there is no mention of the mechanism, just the reaction itself

Comment: The mechanism is not clearly understood. Yet, you may find some insight in [this review](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cej.2018.08.049).